# Crystal Reports - create calendar

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to create an attendence list showing days in rows and employee names in colums. The list will always cover one full month chosen in parameters.

How can I create a recordset of days of chosen month? I've done it in command section but, due to ERP system limitations, it must done otherways.

Thank you,
Przemek

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to create a Calendar table (aka Date Dimension in data warehousing lingo). It makes it easy to show days without any attendance. If you don't need that aspect, you can simply create a formula that returns the attendance date month's day, and Group on that formula. The Day() function gets you the day of month. For example,

```
Day ({Orders.Order Date})
```

If you search 'creating a data dimension or calendar table' you'll find many helpful sources such as this one: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/ 
For your case, I agree with the comments in that post about using date instead of integer as the primary key. Integer PK makes more sense for true data warehousing scenarios as opposed to legacy databases.